# Render Scenes from Sintel movie realistically

Tags: texturing, materials

I am very new to Blender, but I downloaded the official Sintel production files. Has anyone got experience with them?

I can render frames from some scenes, but they look very different from the real movie and it seems some textures and effects are missing.

Let me know if you need any more information, I can also share some files.

Comment: With work and expertise. There is no single way to do it. You may find you need to replace files, change settings, do extra color grading etc in post, and a whole slew of other film production magic.

Comment: Get a version of blender around 2.6